# access is denied while CD a folder in Windows 98

Tags: command-line, windows-98

I have a folder named Protel in Windows 98. I can normally browse it using windows explorer but when I try command

```
cd protel
```

from command prompt it say `Access is Denied`

I know windows 98 has only FAT file system so how is the protection of that folder working

update:

I have installed sp3. this problem only happen when I use run>cmd but it work fine with run>command

Comment: check for disk/file system corruption.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's some non-printable character in folder's name or an unbreakable space. Try using <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete folder name: type `cd Pro` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Windows should autocomplete folder name correctly.

You can try to rename that folder, maybe it will work then.

Comment: Autocomplete did not exist in the commandprompt in windows 98. If my memory is correct it was first introduced in windows 2000 and had to be enabled through a registry key.

Comment: I have installed sp3 of 98 so tab is working but still coming up as access is denied.

Comment: Windows 98 had service packs?

Comment: It is service pack 3 (unofficial). When I used command on RUN it works but It does not works in CMD